# Why I can't see Ubuntu restricted packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, packages, repository

I don't know what else restricted packages are there, but I'm looking for the `sl-modem-daemon` package, which according to http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=sl-modem&searchon=names&suite=saucy&section=all, is a restricted package.

I do have restricted repository in my sources.list:

```
$ grep restricted /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ saucy-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

And having done `apt-get update`, this is what I get:

```
$ apt-cache search sl-modem
sl-modem-dkms - SmartLink software modem driver - module building source
sl-modem-source - SmartLink software modem driver (dummy transitional package)
```

why the `sl-modem-daemon` package is not there while the above ubuntu web page says it should be there?

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 13.10
Release:        13.10
Codename:       saucy
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Oh, it has noting to do with the restricted repository, just the `sl-modem-daemon` package doesn't have the amd64 version in Ubuntu saucy. strange.

```
$ uname -rm
3.11.0-13-generic x86_64
```