# How to install i386 package under amd64 ubuntu/debian

Tags: ubuntu, installation, debian, 64-bit, packages

- All existing answers I found are for the pre-multiarch era (chroot)
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MultiArch says it is OK to install i386 package on amd64 under the multiarch environment, but doesn't say how.

So, how to install i386 package on amd64 under the ubuntu/debian multiarch environment?

This is the follow-up for [Why I can't see Ubuntu restricted packages](https://superuser.com/questions/741368/why-i-cant-see-ubuntu-restricted-packages/741373), where the `sl-modem-daemon` package doesn't have the amd64 but only i386 version in Ubuntu. Following https://askubuntu.com/questions/29665/how-do-i-apt-get-a-32-bit-package-on-a-64-bit-installation, I tried,

```
apt-get install sl-modem-daemon:i386
```

but still get the reply that package not found.

Comment: Works on my machine. It is in restricted - did you enable that repository?

Comment: No, so I guess the missing step is the "enabling that repository". How did you do that?

Comment: Start the "Software and Updates" tool (or go to the repository settings in Synaptic) and check the box called "Proprietary drivers for devices (restricted)". Then run `apt-get update` (if the package lists don't update automatically, which they might).

Comment: As posted in http://superuser.com/questions/741368/why-i-cant-see-ubuntu-restricted-packages/741373, I've enabled the restricted repository (details there). Are you using i386 instead of Amd64?

Comment: No, I'm using Kubuntu Saucy on amd64. Strange - if nothing else, assuming you have all the dependencies, you can always download the package and manually install it with `dpkg -i --force-architecture`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Found the answer in the Debian wiki (the ubuntu community MultiArch wiki is incomplete) -- https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO. I.e., the step I'm missing is

To add an extra architecture (in Debian from dpkg 1.16.2 onwards):

```
dpkg --add-architecture <arch>
```

Having done that (and `apt-get update` of course), I'm now able to do `apt-get install sl-modem-daemon:i386`.

Thank you user55325 for riding the journey with me.

**UPDATE:** Found one that explains this explicitly:

**How to enable 32-bit support for 64-bit Ubuntu 13.10 or greater**
http://www.unixmen.com/enable-32-bit-support-64-bit-ubuntu-13-10-greater/