# Error installing printer in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: printer, ubuntu-18.04, canon-pixma, print-drivers

I'm trying to install the printer Canon PIXMA IP1300. There are no drivers available for this model anymore. Therefore, I downloaded a pack and I'm installing it, through which, accordingly, I'll be able to use the printer.

The pack is called `cnijfilter-ip1900series:i386`. When I am installing it, I get the following error:

```
 dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-ip1900series: i386 (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
  cnijfilter-ip1900series: i386
```

I would appreciate any help, even if only to tell me that this is a waste of time.

Comment: Have you run `apt -f install` after this?

Comment: That should fix it - if it does I'll write an answer explaining it.

Comment: @EugenRieck got it:
`E: Could not open lock file / var / lib / dpkg / lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/ var / lib / dpkg / lock-frontend), are you root?`

Comment: Are you root? If not, you must prefix the command by `sudo` as in `sudo apt -f install`

Comment: @EugenRieck sorry! The error is still there when I try to install the printer pack!

Comment: @EugenRieck now it tells me:

`dpkg: error processing package cnijfilter-ip1900series: i386 (--install):
  dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
  cnijfilter-ip1900series: i386`

Comment: You must run `sudo apt -f install` **AFTER** installing the package, not before. The errors from the `dpkg -i` will then be fixed.

Comment: @EugenRieck however, when I try to install it, it never completes the process!

Comment: It is **installed**, it just isn't **configured** (thus "leaving unconfigured"). The `apt -f` will install all missing dependencies and then configure the package. You can see it in the output of `sudo apt -f install` - it will say "configuring cnijfilter-ip1900series"

Comment: @EugenRieck I don't know... I cannot find the printer drivers. 
I've found this tutorial: https://askubuntu.com/questions/41077/install-i386-printer-driver-on-an-amd64-system

Comment: Do you have an amd64 system? If yes, then installing the i386 drivers will be hard if not impossible. It is definitly not a simple matter of "dpkg -i". You should have mentioned that in your question!

Comment: @EugenRieck sorry for my ignorance, but I don't know. How can I check it out?

Comment: @EugenRieck I've entered a `lshw` and didn't find this specs.

Comment: `uname -i` gives you either "x86" or "x86_64"

Comment: @EugenRieck it gives x86_64. :/  Should I sell it? :(

Comment: I found this answer: https://superuser.com/questions/741380/how-to-install-i386-package-under-amd64-ubuntu-debian

Answer (score 0):

Go to the printer manufacturer's Web site and search for print drivers, printer drivers or drivers.
Find the right driver for your printer model.
Download and install the driver [source: Adobe]. You may have to restart the computer after installing the new driver.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1149366)